# How to invert color of seaborn heatmap colorbar

Tags: colors, heatmap, seaborn

I use an heatmap to visualize a confusion matrix. I like the standard colors, but I would like to have 0s in light orange and highest values in dark purple.

I managed to do so only with another set of colors (light to dark violet), setting:

```
colormap = sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True)
ax = sns.heatmap(cm_prob, annot=False, fmt=".3f", xticklabels=print_categories, yticklabels=print_categories, vmin=-0.05, cmap=colormap)
```

But I want to keep these standard ones. This is my code and the image I get.

```
ax = sns.heatmap(cm_prob, annot=False, fmt=".3f", xticklabels=print_categories, yticklabels=print_categories, vmin=-0.05)
```

[image]

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The default cmap is `sns.cm.rocket`. To reverse it set cmap to `sns.cm.rocket_r`

Using your code:

```
cmap = sns.cm.rocket_r

ax = sns.heatmap(cm_prob,
                 annot=False,
                 fmt=".3f",
                 xticklabels=print_categories,
                 yticklabels=print_categories,
                 vmin=-0.05,
                 cmap = cmap)
```

Comment: for me I have to use `plt.cm` as `sns` does't have `cm` module.

Comment: @AmirhosImani what version of seaborn are you using? It seems like it's still part of the current version (see [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/tree/master/seaborn))

Answer (score 31):

To expand on Ben's answer, you can do this with most if not any color map.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
X = np.random.random((4, 4))
sns.heatmap(X,cmap="Blues")
plt.show()
sns.heatmap(X,cmap="Blues_r")
plt.show()
sns.heatmap(X,cmap="YlGnBu")
plt.show()
sns.heatmap(X,cmap="YlGnBu_r")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- **only add `cmap="rocket_r"` to `sns.heatmap`**

  - `cmap="rocket"`: is the default palette of heatmap
  - add`_r`: to reverse the colors of palette

```py
ax = sns.heatmap(cm_prob, annot=False, fmt=".3f", xticklabels=print_categories, yticklabels=print_categories, vmin=-0.05,cmap="rocket_r")
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to invert the colormap?

```
sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Yep, but, as I already wrote in the question, I want those same standard colors not the ones in cubehelix_palette (which has shades of purple without orange)

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question then. Maybe the other answer is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

we can now quickly achieve reverse color just by putting **_r** in the end.

For example: for **viridis** => **viridis_r**

```
sns.heatmap(corr_matrix, annot=True, cmap='viridis_r');
```